# Migrating BPEL 1.1 to BPEL 2.0 (automation)?

Tags: xml, xslt, oracle12c, soa, bpel

In order to refactor an older process in our Middleware, we decided to either rebuild in BPEL 2.0 or migrate the BPEL process from 1.1 to BPEL 2.0 using Jdeveloper.

I am planning to use the tips portrayed in the following guide for the migration: [Guide for migration by Izaak de Hullu](https://technology.amis.nl/2011/01/27/migrating-your-bpel-1-1-process-to-bpel-2-0-soa-suite-11gr1ps2-to-ps3/). However these tips originate from 2011. I have noticed that the guide by Izaak works, but the amount of manual labor in the process is high. **Does someone have a more recent view on migrating BPEL processes from 1.1 to BPEL 2.0 and posses a written guide? Additionally, is there an xslt out there that can alleviate some of this work?**

Thank you,

Jesper

Comment: I've found another guide: https://narenravi.blogspot.com/2011/08/v-behaviorurldefaultvml-o.html . Most if not all 'manual' actions can be done with a script or on the commandline. Bash has 'sed' for example. Or you open it in a text editor and do find / replace.

Comment: Hey Wesley, this guide is very thorough. Even though it contains no tips on automation, its really lines up all points to create an XSLT or script for automation. If you would post this as an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found another guide: narenravi.blogspot.com/2011/08/v-behaviorurldefaultvml-o.html . Most if not all 'manual' actions can be done with a script or on the commandline. Bash has 'sed' for example. Or you open it in a text editor and do find / replace